# How do I group rowas in Excel based on similar column content inside a text?

Tags: python, vba

I have an excel table and I would like to group a row based on similar content value in one column. This is expressed as a link.
For example I have the input:
[image]

And I would like the output:
[image]

Any tips for how to do the algorithm and any resources available would be really useful! I am quite new to VBA but I would also be happy with solutions using Python. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

How about this as an option?

```
Sub GroupLike()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sht = ActiveSheet
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row


Range("A1:D" & LastRow).Select
Range("D1").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D2:D" & LastRow) _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:D" & LastRow)
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With


Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
j = 0
   For i = 2 To Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
      If Cells(i, "D") = Cells(i + 1, "D") Then
        Cells(i, "D").EntireRow.Group
      End If
   Next i
End Sub
```

First, I'm doing a sort, based on values in ColumnD, and then I'm doing some grouping, again, based on values in ColumnD.

In cell D1, I have this function.

```
=MID(C2,FIND("value",C2,1),6)
```

Here's a screen shot before.

[image]

And, after.

[image]